# Performance difference between equals and ID comparison

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there a performance difference between `obj.equals(obj2)` and `object.ID == obj2.ID`? My understanding is that the equals will be slower than the comparison between IDs especially when the data set is larger and when I use something like a LINQ statement to look for one item

Example:

```
class Person {
    int Id,
    string Name
}

Person a = new Person (1,"Steve");
Person b = new Person (2,"Peter");

//Scenario 1
if (a.equals(b)) {Console.WriteLine("True");}

//Scenario 2
if (a.Id == b.Id) {Console.WriteLine("True");}
```

Comment: No, but in your case, there is a technical one. a.Equals(b) should return false, even if the ID's were the same, unless you override the Equals operator.

Comment: with overriding equals you could only compare ID making them equal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how your `Equals` method is implemented. If you don't override it, the default behavior is to compare references, so two distinct instances with the same ID won't be considered equal. So it's not just a question of performance, but also a question of correctness.

Now, assuming you implement `Equals` so that it compares the IDs of the two instances: it will be a bit slower than the IDs directly (because of the overhead of calling a virtual method), but the difference will probably be too small to be noticeable.

Comment: I am not necessarily concerned about the output of the object comparison in this example. I just wanted to know which one is faster without me overriding the `equals`

Comment: @sujithgokul, I suspect the default implementation is pretty fast, but the only way to know for sure is to benchmark it.

Comment: @sujithgokul: You should be concerned with the correctness of the comparison. A slow correct answer is better than a quick wrong answer. Your two examples are not doing the same thing (unless you override `Equals`)

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: Makes sense. I just wanted to know whether the default implementation can be slower than the ID comparison

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing whether class overrides `Equals` it is not possible to say which one is faster.

By default if class does not override `Equals` then `a.Equals(b)` will perform reference comparison of objects `a` and `b` (resulting in `false` even if objects have the same `.Id`), while `a.Id == b.Id` performs comparison on `Id` which if overridden (like for numeric types) will compare values of the IDs.

So speed-wise first one of these two completely different operations will likely be a bit faster in default case.